# TFS Custom Field Reporting on Historical Value

Tags: tfs, reporting, field

Using Agile template on with some customized fields.

Custom-Field-X is a Drop Down List with allowed value set 0, 1, 2, 3 - this value could change daily.

Need a way to check if Custom-Field-X was ever set to 0 during its life time.

Using TFS2010.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about a custom field you added for TFS workitems. You can use following code to find out whether the value was set to 0 or not. Alternately you can also use  workItemStore.GetWorkItem(id) to get specific workitem by Id. You can find details about retrieving work items @ http://pwee167.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/retrieving-work-items-using-the-team-foundation-server-api/.

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client; 
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client; // You need to add reference to both these assemblies in your project

var collectionUri = new Uri("<TfsUrl>/<CollectionName>"); // For e.g. "http://tfs:8080/DefaultCollection"

var projectCollection = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri);

WorkItemStore workItemStore = projectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

var results = workItemStore.Query("SELECT * FROM WORKITEMS");

WorkItem workItem = results[0];

foreach (Revision revision in workItem.Revisions)
{
    var originalValue = revision.Fields["Custom-Field-X"].OriginalValue;

    var curretValue = revision.Fields["Custom-Field-X"].Value;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, any way to do this via Report Builder or Excel Report route ?

Comment: If you have the TFS data warehouse DB you can look at following link. It might have what you are looking for. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244668(v=vs.90).aspx#WorkItemHistory

Comment: Adarsh - from what I've seen custom fields aren't included in Cube DB.